# How do I write internal style sheets in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, css, zend-framework

I would like to write an internal style sheet to a view in Zend Framework as such

```
<head>
   <style type="text/css" media="all"> 
      body{ background: #FFFFFF; }
   </style>
</head>
```

I understand that I can write an external style sheet using `$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('style.css');`

However I cannot find a way to write an internal style sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "internal style sheet".

Comment: edited the question to clarify internal style sheet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the `HeadStyle` view helper. Its manual documentation can be found [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headstyle).

The `HeadStyle` helper's API is consistent will all the `Head*` view helpers, and works as such (the following assumes you are in a viewscript):

```
// Putting styles in order: 
// These methods assume the a string argument containing the style rules.

// place at a particular offset:
$this->headStyle()->offsetSetStyle(100, $customStyles);

// place at end:
$this->headStyle()->appendStyle($finalStyles);

// place at beginning
$this->headStyle()->prependStyle($firstStyles);

// Or capturing a block of styles

<?php $this->headStyle()->captureStart() ?>
body {
    background-color: <?php echo $this->bgColor ?>;
}
<?php $this->headStyle()->captureEnd() ?>
```

Note that you do not include the `<style>` tags in any of this input. That is generated by the helper itself.
Then, in your layout, simply `echo` the helper where you'd like its output:

```
<head>
    <?php echo $this->headLink() ?>
    <?php echo $this->headStyle() ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. $this->headStyle()->captureStart() and $this->headStyle()->captureEnd() was just what I was looking for.